# Establishing a new TLS Server with incoming HTTP2 Requests

Tags: go, ssl

To comply with company guidelines of utilizing only HTTP2, how can I establish a new TLS with the underlying connection of the HTTP2 request?

I have successfully used the Hijack method on the http.ResponseWriter to retrieve the conn object from an HTTP1.1 request, and with the help of the conn object and TLS configuration, I have established a TLS server. My goal is to establish a TLS server in a similar manner, but with incoming HTTP2 requests.

Code snippet for HTTP1.1 request

```
    hijacker, ok := w.(http.Hijacker)
    if !ok {
        return nil, errors.New("hijacking not supported")
    }
    clientConn, _, err := hijacker.Hijack()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("hijacking failed")
    }
    tlsConn := tls.Server(clientConn, &tlsConfig)
    tlsConn.Write([]byte("hello there"))
```

We are trying to set up a secure server that can handle different certificates based on the hostname. To do this, Service A sends information about the certificate to Service B through HTTP 1.1. Service B uses the certificate information to create a new secure server (TLS). However, if the incoming request is using HTTP2, this process is not possible as HTTP2 does not support retrieving the underlying connection.

The reason for this setup is to allow Service A, which acts as a proxy, to communicate with Service B in a secure manner. The client's original request to Service A may not trust Service B's certificate, so Service A sends the host information to Service B first, allowing B to create a secure server using the proper certificate. Service A then forwards the client's request to this new secure server which is still using the same underlying connection.